Should Services Communicate Directly in a Spring Boot Application Using the Facade Pattern?
I'm working on a Spring Boot application using the Facade Pattern. I understand that facades can communicate with each other and encapsulate multiple services. However, should the services themselves communicate directly, or is it better to manage all interactions at the facade level? Additionally, if there’s common logic needed by multiple services, should I create a separate service for that?

Checkout this blog from confluent and read this from Sam Newman.
In summary micro-services should be "smart end points and dumb pipes" meaning they should have a rich api and dump events onto an event bus for other micro-services to pick up.
Defining microservers and their boundaries is best done with event storming.
